# Is there a way to trigger Javascript function while the JSP loads

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I have a JSP page that fetches database results and takes a lot of time to load, at times when there are over 500 results. I have few questions about this:-

1. Is there a way I can optimize this process? I am using JDBC at my servlet to fetch results and render them to JSP.
2. An alternate approach which I think is to display a "Loading Bar" PNG image while the JSP loads and hide it when the load completes, so that user doesn't go crazy on my UI. So how can I instantiate a Javascript function on JSP initialization and then again call that function when the JSP loading is complete?

Comment: Is it possible for you to change your database SQL to limit the number of results returned? See Limit command http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm

Comment: unfortunately thats not the case. The application is kinda of search application, so whatever mataches the search has to be displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript runs on the client, the JSP code runs on the server. They do not run at the same time so JavaScript is of no use. If it takes a long time, you need to figure out what is the issue on the server and profile your code.

You can try loading the page initially without the records. You can than load the content with an Ajax request.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, considering that I don't have AJAX experience is there any other alternative to expedite the process? I mean prior to AJAX there used to be applications displaying large amount of data.

Comment: Do you know why it is taking forever? Where is the bottleneck? Serverside, rendering on the client? The Ajax solution is easy, but it just hides your real problem.

Comment: @espascarello: It takes allot of time to load when the large data set from the database is asked for, by this i mean the JDBC iterator takes allot of time. Are there any example AJAX codes you would recommend. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using response flush: (JSP)

```
response.setHeader("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");
response.getWriter().write("<html><head><script>alert('this will take awhile');</script></head>");
response.getWriter().flush();
...
/* long running JSP jdbc query and output */
```

Using AJAX or more simply an IFRAME:

```
<!-- home.jsp -->
<html><head></head>
<body>
    <div id="loading">Your content is loading</div>
    <iframe name="content" src="jdbcquery.jsp" onLoad="document.getElementById('loading').innerHTML=='Load Succeeded';">
    </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, is there a way that the JSP gets loaded with data completly and is then displayed at once?

Answer (score 0):

1. You could consider paging. Or dynamically add rows using Ajax when the user scrolls down.
2. You could use the following pseudo code to show an animation while loading.

Pseudo code:

```
<div id="loader">Loading / GIF animation</div>
<div id="result" style="display:none;">
  Lots of data.
  Should be flushed to the browser every now and then.
  This will take seconds...
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#loader").hide();
  $("#result").show();
</script>
```